# jQuery file upload doesn't add file after cancel

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Using [jQuery file upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), not sure what could be wrong, but the I can't re-add files that I have cancelled to the queue.

The `add` callback is not called again for the same file. It is called if I try to upload another file instead.

This is my initialization:

```js
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    maxFileSize: 5000000,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    replaceFileInput: false,
    singleFileUploads: false,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    dropZone: null
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is only seen when I set `replaceFileInput: false`.

To solve that, I have to add the one line of code from:

```php
...
else {
  deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
  that._transition($(this)).done(
      function () {
          $(this).remove();
          that._trigger('failed', e, data);
          that._trigger('finished', e, data);
          deferred.resolve();
      }
  );
}
```

to:

```php
...
else {
  deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
  that._transition($(this)).done(
      function () {
          $('input[type=\"file\"]').val('');
          $(this).remove();
          that._trigger('failed', e, data);
          that._trigger('finished', e, data);
          deferred.resolve();
      }
  );
}
```